# How do I best reference this control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got a TableLayoutPanel to which I am adding controls using the below syntax.

```
tableLayoutPanelTableHeaders.Controls.Add(new Label {Name = "myLabel, "Text = "+", Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold), ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen, AutoSize = true, Enabled = false}, 3, 1);
```

Is there any way for me to reference the label I am creating without having to search for it first? At the moment I have got to search child controls of my TableLayoutPanel for one with a name of "myLabel".

```
Label myLabel = (Label)tableLayoutPanelTableHeaders.Controls.Find("myLabel", true)[0];
```

I know I could create the label first and assign it to a variable like below and then add this to the combobox, but I like how the above code keeps everything on one line.

```
Label myLabel = new Label {Name = "myLabel, "Text = "+", Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold), ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen, AutoSize = true, Enabled = false};
```

Also, does anybody know if creating a control as I am in my first example is referred to by a special term?

Comment: "the above code keeps everything on one line" - at the cost of readability. and gives you trouble later when trying to access label instance. "create the label first and assign it to a variable" sound like a better idea

Comment: "special term" - maybe programatic creation/generation/instantiation of control. open any .designer.cs file, there will be plenty examples of that.

Comment: `(Label)tableLayouPanel1.Controls["label1"]` or `tableLayouPanel1.Controls.Find("label1", true).OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault()` in case the label nested deep in multi level inside the container.

Comment: @RezaAghaei do we really need the Find part?

Comment: @Steve Not really. It's just for learning purpose in case of multi level nesting the label inside some other container.

Comment: @RezaAghaei any special purpose why the `Find` call is before the `OfType` call?

Comment: @MongZhu in case of multiple controls with the same name.

Comment: It's just a comment for someone who don't know they can use `Controls` indexer or  they don't know there is a `Find` method to find controls in multiple nesting level. 
Maybe not a perfect example, but good enough a pointer to  these propertiyes/methods. Any way, not such important to spend much of time to discuss about it ;)

Comment: The `.Add(label = new Label(..` is the only missing notation here. Not that I would recommend it, but this is assignment and creation and storage in a variable in one line.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up assigning my controls to variables as ASh suggested.
Also, I didn't know .Controls had an indexer. Nice one @Reza Aghaei.